# Teamcity engine crashed with parent-modules maven

Tags: java, maven, teamcity, subproject

I have two simple spring projects, both built fine on teamcity. Then I added a parent pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.abcd</groupId>
<artifactId>MainProject</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>

<modules>
<module>employee</module>
<module>SpringOne</module>
</modules>
</project>
```

Then in employee and SpringOne pom.xml files, I added parent tag:
    
        MainProject
        com.abc
        1.0-SNAPSHOT

The new pom files are build fine from command line. But when I moved it to teamcity, I am seeing error with -X -e option:

```
[16:53:17][Step 1/1] Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: The forked VM terminated without saying properly goodbye. VM crash or System.exit called ?
[16:53:17][Step 1/1]    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.output.ForkClient.close(ForkClient.java:257)
[16:53:17][Step 1/1]    at   org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.fork(ForkStarter.java:301)
[16:53:17][Step 1/1]    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run(ForkStarter.java:116)
[16:53:17][Step 1/1]    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeProvider(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:740)
[16:53:17][Step 1/1]    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeAllProviders(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:682)
[16:53:17][Step 1/1]    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeAfterPreconditionsChecked(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:648)
[16:53:17][Step 1/1]    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.execute(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:586  )
[16:53:17][Step 1/1]    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:106)
[16:53:17][Step 1/1]    ... 20 more
[16:53:17][Step 1/1] [main] ERROR org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli - 
[16:53:17][Step 1/1] [main] ERROR org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli - 
[16:53:17][Step 1/1] [main] ERROR org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli - For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[16:53:17][Step 1/1] [main] ERROR org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli - [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginExecutionException
[16:53:17][Step 1/1] [main] ERROR org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli - 
[16:53:17][Step 1/1] [main] ERROR org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli - After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[16:53:17][Step 1/1] [main] ERROR org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli -   mvn <goals> -rf :employee
```

I tried to build the modified employee pom.xml in the teamcity, got similar error:

> [com.abc:employee] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) on project employee: Execution default-test of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test failed: The forked VM terminated without saying properly goodbye. VM crash or System.exit called

Comment: Have you tried to upgrade maven-surefire-plugin to the latest version?

Comment: hmm, I didn't pay attention to the version of maven-surefire-plugin, I will try it tonight. Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide more details about your teamcity build configuration?